# is deleting image from display surface possible without overdrawing it? (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

i want to load an image for 5 seconds and then delete it from the display surface without overwriting it.

I load my image with this function:

```
pygame.image.load('image.png')
```

is there a function that undo this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, once you change a `Surface`, it remains change.

An easy solution is to just create a copy of the target `Surface` before you change it (using `.copy()`) and, if the `Surface` in question is the root `Surface`, simply blit the copy back onto it.